# How to store data with localStorage using JavaScript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

> I'm doing todo-list, and while it saves data in todo task row and completed. inside view https://jsfiddle.net/6rqfd103/.
>   I tried to save it as an array, I saved it, but couldn't get it outside and this is the code when I haven't done anything, show me how, I don't understand this place yet. explain to me. thank you very much

```
var newTaskInput = document.getElementById("new-task");
var addButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var todoTask = document.getElementById("incomplete-tasks");
var completeTask= document.getElementById("completed-tasks");

var createNewTaskElement = function(taskString) {
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  var editInput = document.createElement("input");
  var editButton = document.createElement("button");
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  editInput.type = "text";
  editButton.innerText = "Edit";
  editButton.className = "edit";
  deleteButton.innerText = "Delete";
  deleteButton.className = "delete";

  label.innerText = taskString;

  listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
  listItem.appendChild(label);
  listItem.appendChild(editInput);
  listItem.appendChild(editButton);
  listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);

  return listItem;
}

var addTask = function() {
    if(newTaskInput.value == ""){
        alert("Nhap todoTask Item !");
        return false;
    }
  var listItem = createNewTaskElement(newTaskInput.value);
  todoTask.appendChild(listItem);
  bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);

    newTaskInput.value = "";
    return true;
}

var editTask = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  var editInput = listItem.querySelector("input[type=text");
  var label = listItem.querySelector("label");
    var containsClass = listItem.classList.contains("editMode");

  if(containsClass) {
    label.innerText = editInput.value;
  } else {
    editInput.value = label.innerText;
  }
  listItem.classList.toggle("editMode");  
}

var deleteTask = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  var ul = listItem.parentNode;

  ul.removeChild(listItem);
}

var taskCompleted = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  completeTask.appendChild(listItem);
  bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskIncomplete);
}

var taskIncomplete = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  todoTask.appendChild(listItem);
  bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);
}

var bindTaskEvents = function(taskListItem, checkBoxEventHandler) {
  console.log("Bind list item events");
  var checkBox = taskListItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
  var editButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.edit");
  var deleteButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.delete");

  editButton.onclick = editTask;

  deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;

  checkBox.onchange = checkBoxEventHandler;
}

addButton.addEventListener("click", addTask);

for(var i = 0; i < todoTask.children.length; i++) {
  bindTaskEvents(todoTask.children[i], taskCompleted);
}

for(var i = 0; i < completeTask.children.length; i++) {
  bindTaskEvents(completeTask.children[i], taskIncomplete);
}
```

Comment: Try JSON.stringify() while saving to localstorage and JSON.parse() while getting back array from localstorage.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6rqfd103/ here, Try it with me. thank

Comment: For a proper answer, provide a [mcve], **within** the question itself, not as an external link (or both).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for store HTML in local storage

## for store HTML in local storage

```
 window.localStorage.setItem('todoTask', todoTask.innerHTML);
 window.localStorage.setItem('completeTask', completeTask.innerHTML);
```

## for get HTML in local storage

```
todoTask.innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('todoTask');
completeTask.innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('completeTask');
```